# Running a script on EC2 start and stop

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have an Amazon Ubuntu instance which I stop and start (not terminate). I was wondering if it is possible to run a script on start and stop of the server. Specifically, I am looking at writting a python boto script to take my RDS volume offline when the EC2 server is not running.

Can anyone tell me if this is possible please?

Comment: is this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10125311/2009616) any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. You just have to write an init script and setup proper symbolic links in /etc/rc#.d directories. It will be started with a parameter `start` or `stop` depending on if machine is starting up or shutting down.

Comment: Isnt that only for startup and not shutdown?

Comment: It depends on where do you create the links and how you name them. You can find more info here, I think it is relevant to ubuntu: http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch03.en.html