# AWS cloudFormation doesn't work with official Centos 6 AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I can't get the most simple cloudFormation UserData block to work with Centos 6 AMI.

```
"UserData" : {"Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["",[
    "#!/bin/bash -ex","\n",
    "sudo touch /root/aws-test.txt"]]}
}
```

It works fine with Amazon Linux but nothing happens with the Centos AMI. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The CentOS AMIs from the marketplace does not include cloud-init, so the UserData is not executed.

See this question about creating a custom CentOS AMI that includes cloud-init: [How do I set up cloud-init on custom AMIs in AWS? (CentOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411408/how-do-i-set-up-cloud-init-on-custom-amis-in-aws-centos)