# Cloud-init is not saving user-data on CentOS 5

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, centos5, cloud-init

When I input some user data (a Bash script) from AWS console it's not being saved in the instance and and running.

- I installed Cloud-init from EPEL repo. (v0.6.5). Latest version is not available for CentOS 5.
- I verified with EC2 Meta service (http://169.254.169.254/), my user-data is there.
- I should get a `user-data.txt` file in `/var/lib/cloud/instance/user-data.txt`, but nothing is there. Actually there's no file inside `/var/lib/cloud/`, only the directory structure exists.
- I tried to work with default `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` and a custom one from https://stackoverflow.com/a/23411409 , none worked.
- I checked with `chkconfig --list | grep cloud`, it's enabled.

  ```
  # chkconfig --list | grep cloud
  cloud-config    0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
  cloud-final     0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
  cloud-init      0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
  cloud-init-local    0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
  ```

Any idea what might went wrong? I'm out of ideas!