# aws ec2 docker container update

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I have an AMI in the AwS Marketplace which runs a docker container inside. I want to update the docker container once when the instance is booting the first time.
Of course, I can ssh to the instance and update the container but maybe there is an easier way.

thx

Comment: systemctl with script.sh ?

Comment: `rc` scripts? `cloud-init`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to update the docker container once when the instance is
>   booting the first time

If you want to have updated docker images then you can put these in your [user-data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) of during launch of the instance.

If you want to update ECS-agent then just put this in the user-data.

```
docker pull amazon/amazon-ecs-agent:latest
```

or if you want to update image from ECR then you need to run this but you the instance should have a role to access the ECR.

```
docker pull account_id.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/test:latest
```

you can find user-data section under

Launch instance -> configure instance -> Advanced Details -> user data

[image]

If you want to update to pull image from some private repo add the login command before pulling the image or if you have already the access then just run `docker pull image_name`

update:

If you want to add these in your AMI by default, you can use cloud.ini.

Here is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411408/how-do-i-set-up-cloud-init-on-custom-amis-in-aws-centos) that you can look or [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20150110200930/http://www.scalehorizontally.com/2013/02/24/introduction-to-cloud-init).

Comment: thanks, but I think the most user will forget to paste the docker pull command in the user data field and as far as I know  you cant set this as default

Comment: what is OS you are running in AMI?

Comment: Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS (HVM)

Comment: okay so you can add your command in crontab which will run on boot ,run command `crontab -e` then add `@reboot ( sleep 90 ; sh /home/ubuntu/init_script.sh)` your init_scipt.sh will container `docker pull image` or any other command and rebuild the AMI. tested with ubuntu 18

Comment: @Kev there is interesting answer, I thought you want to update but user has to update. so better to use cloudini.it  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411408/how-do-i-set-up-cloud-init-on-custom-amis-in-aws-centos

Comment: Thats what I am looking for (@masseyb also mentioned it), thx for your time

Comment: yes, I just thought that user has to update but later I convinced from your comment that it should be part of AMI instead of user-data.

Comment: Thanks for appreciation @LinPy , one thing more would like to connect over linked if possible

Comment: oh I see, I will give it try :)