# The AWS user data option isn't functioning

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, ec2-userdata

Using the AWS console, I'm launching an instance using a custom AMI. A few XML files need to be updated as part of the system initialization. Although I entered the user data, it doesn't appear to be working. Even though I tried simple things like echoing in a file, it still doesn't work.

```
[root@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx ~]# curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data
#!/bin/bash
echo "Shiv" >  /tmp/check1.txt
echo "all" > check.txt[root@ip-172-31-40-190 ~]# timed out waiting for input: auto-logout
```

Nothing related to cloud keyword is present in `/var/log/message`:

```
grep -inr "cloud" /var/log/messages
```

[image: User data entered]

It even doesn't have the file `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`. What am I missing in this situation?

Comment: Are you saying that you launched a **new** EC2 instance with this User Data, and that the instance had never booted previously? The User Data should run **once per Instance ID**.

Comment: If this is a custom AMI, did you empty out `/var/lib/cloud/` before creating the image?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes, it's a freshly launched instance from the AMI.

Comment: @AnonCoward /var/lib/cloud/ does not exist.

Comment: Would you know which AMI was used as the basis for this AMI? For example, Amazon Linux 2 includes cloud-init, but perhaps the AMI that was originally used does not have cloud-init installed?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein We have an on-premises solution . Installing an ISO file is what we do. Our goal is to offer support on AWS. I created an AMI from that ISO using "https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-image-import.html".

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I did some research and go to know that "AWS user data does not require any specific AWS package to be part of your Amazon Machine Image (AMI) to work. User data is a feature of Amazon EC2 instances that allows you to run commands or scripts when an instance is launched. It does not depend on any particular AWS package being included in the AMI. As long as the instance has internet connectivity and the necessary permissions, it can execute user data scripts regardless of the AMI's contents."

Comment: That is incorrect. While User Data is provided to every Amazon EC2 instance, the magic that takes the User Data and executes it as a script is a utility called `cloud-init` that must be installed on the instance. (Can you share a link to the information you quoted?)

Comment: Thank you. I'll try adding the cloud-init package. One more question: is having the package included in the AMI sufficient, or does cloud-init require additional configuration? 

I looked it up on ChatGPT, and it seems I shouldn't rely on it for information.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Added the packet                                                                  
[root@ip-xx-xx-x-xx tmp]# rpm -qa | grep "cloud-init"
cloud-init-19.4-12.xxxx.x86_64
but it is still not working.  Diractory /var/lib/cloud exists and is empty.  Is having the package included in the AMI sufficient, or does cloud-init require additional configuration?

Comment: Might help: [How do I set up cloud-init on custom AMIs in AWS? (CentOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23411408/174777)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are [Importing a VM as an image using VM Import/Export - VM Import/Export](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-image-import.html). As a result, your instance does not have `cloud-init` installed.

`cloud-init` is a utility that will runs scripts at launch:

> Cloud images are operating system templates and every instance starts out as an identical clone of every other instance. It is the user data that gives every cloud instance its personality and **cloud-init is the tool that applies user data to your instances automatically**.

When you boot an Amazon EC2 instance, it runs an operating system. The operating system is responsible for running processes on the instance, responding to scripts, command-lines, etc. It's just like any normal computer. The process that runs scripts at launch is called `cloud-init`.

If `cloud-init` is installed on an EC2 instance then it will look in the User Data nd run the script **once per instance ID**. It can also run in other situations depending on configuration.

`cloud-init` is installed on Amazon Linux, Unbuntu and some other AMIs.

Since you are creating your own AMI from an external VM, **you will need to install `cloud-init` to make User Data scripts run on first boot**.

A bit of history... User Data was originally just a way to 'pass some information' to the instance (hence the name 'user data'). It was Canonical who first conceived of the idea that it would be possible to **pass a script** via User Data. The created `cloud-init` and it has become a standard for many cloud computing platforms.