# mysqld service stops once a day on ec2 server

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, mysql

Environment Details:

```
Server: Amazon ec2 Linux
Web Server: Apache
Web Framework: Django with mod_wsgi
```

Following I have found in the mysql_err.log file.

```
The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
120823  3:21:40 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
120823  3:21:40 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
120823  3:21:40 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
120823  3:21:41 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
120823  3:21:41 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
120823  3:21:41 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
120823  3:21:41 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
120823  3:21:41 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
120823  3:21:41 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
120823  3:21:41 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Looks like the system memory is not sufficient to allocate memory to buffer pool. Same error happens when I was using `Amazon ec2 micro instance`, So I moved to the `small instance`. It works fine for some days but now it is breaking once in a day again. Is there a permanent fix for that? I can move to medium instance but the issue is will that be fixed or not? Should I decrease the `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, what is the preferred size?

The result of `cat /proc/meminfo` is following (may be it will help):

```
MemTotal:        1697824 kB
MemFree:          125744 kB
Buffers:          109704 kB
Cached:           481408 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          1212396 kB
Inactive:         266840 kB
Active(anon):     888192 kB
Inactive(anon):       76 kB
Active(file):     324204 kB
Inactive(file):   266764 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                 4 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        888144 kB
Mapped:            15604 kB
Shmem:               144 kB
Slab:              63752 kB
SReclaimable:      53680 kB
SUnreclaim:        10072 kB
KernelStack:         800 kB
PageTables:        16436 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:      848912 kB
Committed_AS:    1417140 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:       10988 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359725168 kB
DirectMap4k:     1748992 kB
DirectMap2M:           0 kB
```

OS version (uname -a):
`Linux ip-10-246-134-149 3.2.21-1.32.6.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Sat Jun 23 02:32:15 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I checked the `ps aux` command whet the server has like only 15MB of memory left and these are the `httpd` process running at that time:

The result of `free -m`

```
total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1657       1628         29          0          3         19
-/+ buffers/cache:       1605         51
Swap:          895        875         20
```

The result of `ps aux`

```
apache   21123  0.1  1.2 394652 20464 ?        S    19:35   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21146  0.1  1.2 394280 20796 ?        S    19:38   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21152  0.1  1.2 394284 21560 ?        S    19:38   0:05 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21155  0.2  1.4 396244 24528 ?        S    19:38   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21156  0.1  1.1 392552 20344 ?        S    19:38   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21157  0.1  1.1 394284 18884 ?        S    19:38   0:05 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21159  0.1  1.4 396200 25040 ?        S    19:38   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21161  0.1  1.2 394856 21724 ?        S    19:38   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21162  0.1  1.3 394864 22400 ?        S    19:38   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21163  0.1  1.3 394860 22204 ?        S    19:38   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21164  0.1  1.1 392560 19204 ?        S    19:38   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21165  0.1  1.3 394832 22280 ?        S    19:38   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21166  0.1  1.3 395276 22932 ?        S    19:38   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21172  0.2  1.4 396320 24820 ?        S    19:38   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21174  0.2  1.7 400672 29452 ?        S    19:39   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21178  0.1  1.4 400540 25304 ?        S    19:39   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21179  0.2  1.6 400580 27856 ?        S    19:39   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21184  0.1  1.7 400628 29320 ?        S    19:39   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21185  0.1  1.6 397944 27292 ?        S    19:39   0:05 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21186  0.1  1.5 397960 25648 ?        S    19:39   0:05 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21187  0.1  1.7 400576 29120 ?        S    19:39   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21191  0.1  1.4 400576 24400 ?        S    19:39   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21193  0.1  1.4 400536 24940 ?        S    19:39   0:05 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21194  0.1  1.5 400572 26096 ?        S    19:39   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21203  0.1  1.6 400580 28808 ?        S    19:39   0:05 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21206  0.1  1.7 400584 29732 ?        S    19:39   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21207  0.1  1.6 400576 27940 ?        S    19:39   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21224  0.1  1.2 400624 20768 ?        S    19:39   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21225  0.1  1.6 400576 28468 ?        S    19:39   0:05 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21226  0.1  1.6 400576 28048 ?        S    19:39   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21228  0.1  1.4 400572 23880 ?        S    19:39   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21237  0.1  1.5 400628 26124 ?        S    19:39   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21265  0.1  1.6 400536 28592 ?        S    19:39   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21276  0.1  1.2 400544 21456 ?        S    19:39   0:05 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21277  0.1  1.3 400624 22676 ?        S    19:39   0:05 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21278  0.1  1.6 400536 27360 ?        S    19:39   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21282  0.1  1.4 400612 24996 ?        S    19:39   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21292  0.1  1.4 400532 24780 ?        S    19:39   0:05 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21302  0.2  1.2 400540 21332 ?        S    19:39   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21303  0.1  1.3 400628 22228 ?        S    19:39   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21305  0.2  1.2 400536 21116 ?        S    19:39   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21306  0.1  1.3 400572 22380 ?        S    19:39   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21307  0.1  1.1 397956 20056 ?        S    19:39   0:05 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21308  0.1  1.2 400624 21520 ?        S    19:39   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21319  0.1  1.1 400540 19468 ?        S    19:39   0:05 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21320  0.1  1.3 400628 22712 ?        S    19:39   0:05 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21335  0.1  1.0 400540 17236 ?        S    19:39   0:05 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21336  0.1  1.3 400628 22188 ?        S    19:39   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21352  0.1  1.1 394276 18972 ?        S    19:40   0:04 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21356  0.1  1.1 394280 19028 ?        S    19:40   0:05 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21358  0.1  1.1 394280 19004 ?        S    19:40   0:05 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21361  0.2  0.7 400452 12632 ?        S    19:40   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21610  0.2  1.6 400536 27660 ?        S    19:46   0:06 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21643  0.2  1.3 400156 23272 ?        S    19:55   0:04 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21647  0.2  1.0 400544 17556 ?        S    19:57   0:05 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21654  0.2  1.5 400188 26884 ?        S    19:58   0:05 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21719  0.3  1.9 400192 32264 ?        S    20:14   0:03 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21725  0.2  2.0 400044 35340 ?        S    20:15   0:03 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   21738  0.0  0.8 257648 13792 ?        S    20:26   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
```

Can any one one has an idea about it why there is so much httpd process??

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284532/amazon-ec2-mysql-aborting-to-start-because-innodb-mmap-549453824-bytes-fai

Comment: I checked that i've swap space for 895MB which was turned off, I turned it ON, lets see if that works??

Comment: This crash happens once in a week now, instead swap 895Mb is ON.

Comment: No luck for me in the answers, I tried every thing, At last i have moved to Amazon Ec2 Ubuntu 12.04 (Medium Instance) and the site is working fine for two weeks now.

Comment: Hi where do I find this file n AWS please. I am noticing this more than once per day.

Comment: Why oh why are you not using and RDS and not an pull your SQL server out of your EC2 instance it will be far more stable.

Comment: Upgrading the RAM might help.

Answer (score 45):

#### Use 50% of available RAM to test:

You can decrease the innodb_buffer_pool_size very low to see if it helps:

```
#/etc/my.cnf 
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1M
```

A rule of thumb is to set innodb_buffer_pool_size to 50% of available RAM for your low memory testing. This means you start the server and everything *except* MySQL InnoDB. See how much RAM you have. Then use 50% of that for InnoDB.

To try many low-memory settings at once:

- http://paragasu.wordpress.com/2008/12/02/very-low-memory-mysql-5-mycnf-configuration/

A more likely culprit is whatever else is on that server, such as a webserver.

#### Apache?

Are you using Apache and/or another webserver? If so, try to decrease its RAM usage. For example in Apache conf, consider low RAM settings like these:

```
StartServers 1
MinSpareServers 1
MaxSpareServers 5
MaxClients 5
```

And cap the requests like this:

```
MaxRequestsPerChild 300
```

Then restart Apache.

#### mod_wsgi:

If you're using Apache with mod_python, switch to Apache with mod_wsgi.

#### Pympler:

If it's still happening, possibly your Django is steadily growing. Try Django memory profiling with Pympler:

- http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/profiling-django-object-size-and-memory-usage-pympler/

#### SAR:

Your report of once-per-day failures, then once-per-week failures, could point to some kind of cron job running daily or weekly. For example, perhaps there's a batch process that takes up a lot of RAM, or a database dump, etc.

To track RAM use and look for RAM spikes in the hour before MySQL dies, take a look at SAR, which is a great tool: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/03/sar-examples/

Comment: Thanks for your answer i will mark this accepted, and once i test it i will still award you extra bounty on that.

Comment: The `innodb_buffer_pool_size` tip worked for me. I had a very unstable wordpress instance running on an EC2 t2.micro instance. Mysqlq would crash every few hours and give an `Error connecting to database` error. I added:  `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 200K` to my.cnf and now it is much more stable.

Answer (score 9):

You have to decrease you innodb_buffer_pool_size = <60-80% of your main memory)

Solution for Innodb Error:

```
110603  7:34:15 [ERROR] Plugin ‘InnoDB’ init function returned error.
110603  7:34:15 [ERROR] Plugin ‘InnoDB’ registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
110603  7:34:15 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
110603  7:34:15 [ERROR] Aborting

10603  7:34:15 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

I moved the ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile01 to bak and start Mysql again. Now this time, it is working fine

[root@xxx mysql]# mv ib_logfile0 ib_logfile0-bak
[root@xxx mysql]# mv ib_logfile1 ib_logfile1-bak
```

Source: http://www.onaxer.com/tag/error-plugin-innodb-init-function-returned-error/

Comment: Facing the same problem. It works fine for a while and then same issue again. Error establishing a database connection. I have to manually SSH into the server and start mysql service

Answer (score 3):

Like others have mentioned, the problem appears to be your system running low on RAM and MySQL is blowing up due to that.  Below is how to go about narrowing down where your system's memory is being used and how to recover from the database going down.

Take a look at [collectd](http://collectd.org/index.shtml) and its plugins.  Some of the applicable ones may be the [processes plugin](http://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin%3aProcesses) and the [memory plugin](http://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin%3aMemory).  With those you can see your systems' memory usage and what processes are taking up most of it.

Depending on how you are running Django, you can configure the worker processes to only process a certain number of requests and then terminate.  That way if there is some sort of memory leak in your application it will not persist past that number of requests.  For example, if you use [Gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/), you can use the [--max-requests](http://gunicorn.org/configure.html#max-requests) option.  Setting it to 500 will drop the worker after it has processed 500 requests.

The above combined with stats collection will show you some interesting memory usage trends.

As for the database going down, you can setup process supervision so that if MySQL does die, it will be relaunched automatically.  MySQL in latest version of Ubuntu uses Upstart to do just that.  If the process dies, Upstart will bring it back up immediately.  If you're using another distro that doesn't have this built-in, take a look at [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/).  While this doesn't fix the problem it will at least mitigate its effects.  This should not be seen as the fix but rather a way to keep your application running in case something does go wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Once I got stuck in similar issues, I was really frustrated that my users see this ugly message that **Error Establishing DB Connection**. Instead of resolving the exact issues I found [this repo](https://github.com/sierracircle/services-checker) to work like a charm for me (temporarily). After that I got debugged it by my friend and he just fine tuned my server with some configuration changes. But I've still added this script to my crontab every 10 minutes and then check if the server is crashed (which for my case crashed eventually whenever I run VNCServer on my server) and then restart it

Answer (score 1):

I found answer adds on this discussion and worked for me: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/mysql-server-keeps-stopping-unexpectedly?answer=26016

you have to do both `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to something reasonable like **32M** on `my.conf` in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, and you also may need to modify `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_prefork.conf` to reduce the number of connections started by apache;

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers     3
    MinSpareServers  3
    MaxSpareServers  5
    MaxRequestWorkers 25
    MaxConnectionsPerChild  0
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the available RAM by adding new Swap space might also help. Steps are [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Make sure that you create /swapfile of the size smaller than the available space shown by

```
df -h
```

For example for me output of df- h was:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  1.2G  6.3G  16% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            492M   12K  492M   1% /dev
tmpfs           100M  336K   99M   1% /run
```

So I created using 2 G

```
sudo fallocate -l 2G /swapfile
```

And then just start the service

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Hope this helps. All the best.

Comment: Note quite enough just to use fallocate - You'd missing 3-4 commands before the swap file is mounted. More information here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04