# MySQL crashed with un-answered memory issue

Tags: mysql, wordpress, ubuntu, crash, mariadb-10.4

My website (Wordpress) sometimes stopped working with message "cannot connect to Datatabse".

I checked the log file of MySQL and I found the following crash-info:

```
---------- 
2021-01-21  0:44:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2021-01-21  0:44:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-01-21  0:44:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-01-21  0:44:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-01-21  0:45:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-01-21  0:45:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-01-21  0:45:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-01-21  0:45:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2021-01-21  0:45:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=215993122
2021-01-21  0:45:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2021-01-21  0:45:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-01-21  0:45:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-01-21  0:45:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-01-21  0:45:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-01-21  0:45:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-01-21  0:45:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-01-21  0:45:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2021-01-21  0:45:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=215993122
2021-01-21  0:50:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2021-01-21  0:50:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-01-21  0:50:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-01-21  0:50:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-01-21  0:50:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-01-21  0:50:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-01-21  0:50:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-01-21  0:50:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2021-01-21  0:50:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=215993122
2021-01-21  0:50:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-01-21  0:50:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2021-01-21  0:50:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-01-21  0:50:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-01-21  0:50:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: File '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-01-21  0:50:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-01-21  0:50:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 215993131; transaction id 221150
2021-01-21  0:50:02 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-01-21  0:50:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /opt/lampp/var/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2021-01-21  0:50:02 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
----------
```

I restarted MySQL and my website worked well.
The version of my MySQL is: Distrib 10.4.11-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64)
Ubuntu version 20.

This situation appeared a few times in the last month.

I searched the solution in some posts before.

I've already tried this configuration:

```
max_connections = 100  
key_buffer = 50M
max_allowed_packet = 10M
thread_stack = 128K
table_cache = 50
```

but it still downed.

This is one source I've already found about my problem:
[MySQL keeps crashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19282583/mysql-keeps-crashing/20570269)

Does anyone encountered the same issue, and knows a fix?

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
AND Optional helpful information, if available includes -
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck, Let me check, thanks

Comment: I use VPS server (1G RAM, 1CPU, 25GB SSD). This is from Top command: top - 02:21:44 up 205 days, 59 min, 1 user, load average: 0.01, 0.02, 0.00 Tasks: 99 total, 1 running, 98 sleeping, 0 stopped, 0 zombie %Cpu(s): 3.0 us, 1.7 sy, 0.0 ni, 95.3 id, 0.0 wa, 0.0 hi, 0.0 si, 0.0 st MiB Mem : 981.2 total, 82.0 free, 470.6 used, 428.6 buff/cache MiB Swap: 0.0 total, 0.0 free, 0.0 used. 349.2 avail Mem

Comment: Dear @WilsonHauck, I solved this issue, and I will close this question, many thanks to support me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this question at

https://serverfault.com/questions/1051060/my-mysql-crashed-many-times-in-a-month/1051369#1051369

And I will close this question, many thanks to support me !