# Mysql on Debian stop working suddenly

Tags: mysql, debian

I've installed a vps on DigitalOcean with Debian x64 under ISPConfig 3. 
From time to time Mysql stops working suddenly. I get these from the error log:

```
141115 16:36:11 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
141115 16:36:11 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
2014-11-15 16:36:11 0 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
2014-11-15 16:36:11 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Warning] Buffered warning: Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)

2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Warning] Buffered warning: Changed limits: table_cache: 431 (requested 2000)

2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [ERROR] Function 'innodb' already exists
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'innodb' with soname 'ha_innodb.so'.
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [ERROR] Function 'federated' already exists
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'federated' with soname 'ha_federated.so'.
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [ERROR] Function 'blackhole' already exists
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'blackhole' with soname 'ha_blackhole.so'.
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [ERROR] Function 'archive' already exists
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'archive' with soname 'ha_archive.so'.
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [ERROR] Aborting

2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Binlog end
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2014-11-15 16:36:11 15251 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

141115 16:36:11 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Comment: This is a programming site, this issue has nothing to do with programming. You want Super User, or even better the DB Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is at **InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12**

try this [mysqld service stops once a day on ec2 server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114746/mysqld-service-stops-once-a-day-on-ec2-server)