# Mysql / InnoDB stops working?

Tags: mysql

I've been running a new server instance fine for the past two weeks. Starting today, mysql stoped working by itself, and here is the logs I'm getting.

```
130922 13:32:39 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130922 13:32:39 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130922 13:32:39 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
130922 13:32:39 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
130922 13:32:39 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(135987200 bytes) failed; errno 12
130922 13:32:39 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130922 13:32:39 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
130922 13:32:39 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
130922 13:32:39 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
130922 13:32:39 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
130922 13:32:39 [ERROR] Aborting
130922 13:32:39 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

From what I'm looking at, it seems that there is a problem allocating memory to the databases (there are only a wordpress installed on this machine)... Although, Googling around gives me multiple answers to multiple problem, and I'm not quite sure what do do now.

Right now, the only way to solve the problem is to reboot the machine, then mysql will work again until the next time I see that kind of messages in the log.

Should I try to find a way to change anything in my.cnf for memory? Or is there any other avenue that you could suggest?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Amazon EC2, mysql aborting start because InnoDB: mmap (x bytes) failed; errno 12](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284532/amazon-ec2-mysql-aborting-start-because-innodb-mmap-x-bytes-failed-errno-12)

Comment: Probably overallocated RAM, with no swap space. Recommend increasing RAM on the server, or decreasing `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I moved the server over new specs with higher memory and it seems it did the trick, as @Bill-Karwin suggested.