# Amazon EC2, mysql aborting even after adding swap space

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I have set up a micro instance server on amazon EC2.

mysql server fails frequently and due to which I get 'error establishing a database connection' whenever I access my website. To make my website work again,  I have to restart mysqld. [Here is the error log](https://i.imgur.com/5glHUOb.jpg). Please click the link as i just opened the account on stackoverflow.

I read through [other threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284532/amazon-ec2-mysql-aborting-start-because-innodb-mmap-x-bytes-failed-errno-12) here for the same kind of error and accordingly I added a swapfile of 3G but I am still getting the same memory allocation error. Here is [my swapfile](https://i.imgur.com/zefwCgM.jpg).

I am not a technical person so please help me figure out how to solve this problem.

Comment: Read your logs and you will likely find that your web server is the actual problem, with MySQL being sacrificed by the OS to handle memory demands from the web server.   See [Why is Apache Running Wild and Killing MySQL?](http://serverfault.com/questions/562453/why-is-apache-running-wild-and-killing-mysql) at Server Fault.