# Mysql won't start anymore

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I wanted to check out my logserver again, but all of sudden i get this message when i visit the url:

I am running on ubuntu xenial

FATAL: Cannot connect to MySQL server on 'localhost'. Please make sure you have specified a valid MySQL database name in 'include/config.php'

when i do journalctl -xe i get the following message:

```
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
Jun 15 19:26:12 arjanlog audit[3665]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/3665/status" pid=3665 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=112 ouid=112

Jun 15 19:26:12 arjanlog audit[3665]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=3665 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=112 ouid=0

Jun 15 19:26:12 arjanlog audit[3665]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/3665/status" pid=3665 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=112 ouid=112
Jun 15 19:26:12 arjanlog kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1497547572.504:69): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" 
name="/proc/3665/status" pid=3665 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_m

Jun 15 19:26:12 arjanlog kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1497547572.504:70): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=3665 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r"

Jun 15 19:26:12 arjanlog kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1497547572.504:71): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/3665/status" pid=3665 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_m

Jun 15 19:26:12 arjanlog systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

Comment: I'd say by the word `DENIED`, it seems to be a permissions issue.

Comment: Try this: `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

Comment: @Edward mysql-server is already the newest version (5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)

Answer (score 9):

I had this problem too and solved it by fixing the apparmor configuration file at `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`. I added these lines:

```
  /proc/*/status r,
  /sys/devices/system/node/ r,
  /sys/devices/system/node/node0/meminfo r,
```

Your `journalctl -xe` output shows the files MySQL needs permission to use. You can also look in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Jun 15 19:26:12 arjanlog audit[3665]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/3665/status" pid=3665 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=112 ouid=112
Jun 15 19:26:12 arjanlog audit[3665]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=3665 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=112 ouid=0
Jun 15 19:26:12 arjanlog audit[3665]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/3665/status" pid=3665 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=112 ouid=112
```

That means that `/usr/sbin/mysqld` was `DENIED` trying to open `/proc/3665/status` and `/sys/devices/system/node/` for reading (`r`).

Note that in the apparmor config file the trailing slash in `/sys/devices/system/node/` is necessary, so don't leave it off!

Comment: For me, this removed the error messages, but MySQL still failed to start. I finally look at the MySQL error log (e.g., `/var/log/mysql/error.log`) and noticed errors allocating memory for MySQL (e.g., ` InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool`). Turns out, my EC2 instance didn't have a swap drive. I followed the instructions here to create one and MySQL started right up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284532/amazon-ec2-mysql-aborting-start-because-innodb-mmap-x-bytes-failed-errno-12

Answer (score 2):

It may not be necessary to stop apparmor entirely. It should be sufficient brute force to disable apparmor for mysqld, if you don't want to track down the core issue:

`ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld /etc/apparmor.d/disable/usr.sbin.mysqld`

Answer (score 1):

For me the error was that the mysql database got corrupted. I could see that when I went to logs `/var/log/mysql/error.log` and it showed an error:

```
InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
```

There were some solutions out there which someone could use like [table corruption issue](https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/mysql-wont-start-because-of-innodb-table-corruption)

But it didn't work for me as I wasn't able to start a server in `WRITE` mode in order to solve the issue.

I managed to solve the issue by creating a copy of directory `/var/lib/mysql` - I copied to `mysql.old` and then deleted the `mysql` directory.

Then I called a command in terminal:

```
sudo mysqld --initialize --initialize-insecure
```

To generate a new `mysql` directory

I have then changed permissions of new directory by changing the user and group of `mysql` directory to user: `mysql` and group: `mysql`. Use `chown` command:

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

Then I called command:

```
sudo mysql -u root
```

and changed password with:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR root@'localhost' = PASSWORD('newpassword');
```

And then restarted mysql server:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

And everything worked.

---

Some of the commands that I have used along the way were (although not sure how much they contributed to fixing the issue):

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install mysql-server-5.7
```

Comment: I had to disable the mysql profile for apparmor first, else it wouldnt let me reinit mysql.

Answer (score 1):

I read in another SO thread comment that the `apparmor="DENIED"` message probably isn't the reason that MySQL (or in my case MariaDB) wasn't starting, as it's only a warning.

In my case updating and upgrading apt-installed packages and rebooting the system solved the problem.

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo reboot
```

Then you'll need to wait a few minutes while the system restarts and log back in and restart the service(s) with either `service`, `systemctl` and I think possibly `/etc/system.d`.

Then MariaDB was chugging away happily.

There's a good post on the various `apt upgrade` commands [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/81594/288518), and I think that what `update` does is update the source lists.

I had found this command useful as well, when there were no log files in `/var/log/mysql`:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this bug when I tried to move mysql file from /var/lib/mysql to somewhere else.

add config to /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld didn't work for me

then i got this [bug for ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.7/+bug/1610765)

it said:

```
sudo nano /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
line 25 after:
# Allow config access
  /etc/mysql/** r,
-add line:
  /etc/mysql/* r,
```

and it works for me:

add `/etc/mysql/* r,` to `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`

run `systemctl restart apparmor.service`

and `service mysql start`

Answer (score 0):

After I followed the instructions given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45986591 I was still not able to make the MySql server run. I checked its logs via `tail -30 /var/log/mysql/error.log` . This line caught my attention `2019-05-21T04:46:03.462807Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool`. By reading the previous line of code, I was that it was trying to allocate 128MB of memory. Then I checked my Memory status and it was only 111 Mb free. I stopped few programs (node servers) and restarted the MySql and it started working. Then i commented all the AppArmor entries I had entered and restarted AppArmor and MySql. MySql started without any errors. So I could conclude that MySql was not getting enough memory to get started.

Answer (score -3):

solved by : sudo service apparmor teardown