# what exactly is Amazon EBS Volume and instance store and why is it needed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am new to AWS and trying to understand what is Amazon EBS and instance store and why is it needed ?

Comment: [Benefits of EBS vs. instance-store (and vice-versa)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630506/benefits-of-ebs-vs-instance-store-and-vice-versa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple rule of thumb is:

**Use Amazon EBS unless you have a specific reason to use Instance Store**

Instance Store is mostly an older technology from the days before EBS. See [amazon ec2 - Benefits of EBS vs. instance-store (and vice-versa) - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630506/benefits-of-ebs-vs-instance-store-and-vice-versa) for information about the differences.

A few reasons you might choose Instance Store are:

- Instances are totally ephemeral and you will never need to snapshot/restore their disks
- You need *really fast storage*, since Instance Store is locally attached
- You're particularly cheap, and you'd rather spend several hours of your time saving a few cents on storage